# How do I properly align buttons to the bottom of the parent?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I`m using Flexbox to make the height of the bootstrap columns equal. I do this with:

```
.u-row--eqheight {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.u-row--eqheight:before,
.u-row--eqheight:after {
    display: block;
}

.u-row--eqheight > [class*='col-'] {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
 <div class="row u-row--eqheight">
    <?php foreach($posts as $post) : ?>
        <div class="col-xxs-24 col-xs-8 col-md-8 blog">
            <a href="<?= adjustURL($post->getPermalink()) ?>"> 
                <?php if ($featuredImage = $post->getFeaturedImage()) : ?>
                    <div class="blog__image" style="background-image: url(<?= $featuredImage->getFullSizeImage() ?>)"></div>
                <?php endif ?>

                <div class="blog__title">
                    <?= $this->htmlEscape($post->getPostTitle()) ?>
                </div>

                <div class="blog__caption">
                    <?= trimExcerpt($post->getPostExcerpt()) ?>
                </div>

                <div class="blog__read-more">Lees verder</div>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

This is the SCSS:

```
.blog {
    margin-bottom: $mb-twenty;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.blog a {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 100%;
}

.blog__image {
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-bottom: 64%;
    margin-bottom: $mb-ten;
}

.blog__title {
    font-family: 'Asap', $font-fallback-sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.188rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.188rem;
    margin-bottom: $mb-ten;
    word-break: break-word;
}

.blog__caption {
    color: $gray-dark;
    margin-bottom: $mb-ten;
    word-break: break-word;
}

.blog__read-more {
    margin-top: auto;
    text-align: right;
}
```

This will turn out as this on Chrome which is fine, everything is nicely aligned:

[image: 3 Columns on Chrome]

But on Firefox it is like this which adds problems to content below the columns:

[image: 3 Colums on Firefox]

How do I do this propery with Flexbox and browser compatibility?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It will be compatible if you use bootstrap grid properly

Comment: Mind explaining what I`m doing wrong?

Comment: Ok could you please make a fiddle for your problem , so that we can easily track the issue.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ov3j2cyp/ for some weird reason the columns are not showing side by side at this jsfiddle, even though I added bootstrap..

Comment: @japortegijs  "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery " --- could you add jquery in your fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ov3j2cyp/4/ sorry, updated

Comment: Source of your problem: `padding-bottom: 64%` on the image elements.